# how to load new rss feed items in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jfeed, jquery-xml

I'm using jFeed to parse an RSS feed, but I'm thinking now how I can track changes on interval based checking. How would one efficiently check if there are new items in a feed compared to the previous load? Unfortunately I can't use the RSS 2.0 last updated parameter, as it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! See the following solution:

```
//namespace for vars
$.feedentries = { 
    lastKnownEntry : ""
}; 

jQuery.getFeed({
    url: 'proxy.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(url),
    success: function(data) {
        //if new iterate through it until we've found the last know entry
        if(data.items[0].title!==$.feedentries.lastKnownEntry){
            var entries = "";
            $.each(data.items, function(i, feed) {
                if(feed.title!==$.feedentries.lastKnownEntry){
                    entries += '<div class="rss-entry">'+feed.title+'<div class="time"><a href="'+feed.link+'">'+feed.updated+"</a></div></div>\n";
                    //remove last element, prevents from overflowing
                    $(id+" .rss-entry:last-child").remove();
                } else {
                    //stop once we reach last known entry
                    return false;
                }
            });
            //insert into DOM
            $(id).prepend(entries);
            //write new last known rss title
            $.feedentries.lastKnownEntry = data.items[0].title;
        }
    }
});
```